# nginx container fail to start

Tags: docker, nginx

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY  /root/fe/foodsafe /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I found in the nginx image doc:

> *If you add a custom CMD in the Dockerfile, be sure to include -g daemon off; in the CMD in order for 
>      nginx to stay in the foreground, so that Docker can track the process properly (otherwise your 
>      container will stop immediately after starting)!*

but I didn't write any CMD in the Dockerfile, what's wrong?

Comment: To be able to help we need (as a minimum) to see the error message you're getting, the nginx.conf and what's inside /root/fe/foodsafe. The CMD note is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @MikaelKjær  there is no error, the container just start and exit immediately, I believe it's due to the daemon, but I dont' t know why the nginx run in the background

Comment: @MikaelKjær I'm sorry, I've write the wrong nginx.conf , that's the mistake.